# How to add a calculated value as parameter in JMeter request?

Tags: jmeter

I have two variables available in my JMeter script. One of them param_A is extracted from the response of a request using a regular expression extractor and other param_B I am reading from a csv file using a csv data config.

I need to use param_C in another http POST request which takes param_C along with some other values too.
But I need to ensure that param_C is product of param_A and param_B

So, I need to perform
param_C = param_A * param_B;

I can now use param_C as a variable in request payload of my http post request.

Could someone help me how can I really do so?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a [JMeter Function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) to multiply these "params", for example [__jexl3()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) would be a good candidate, the relevant syntax:

```
${__jexl3(${param_A} * ${param_B},param_C)}
```

And demo:

[image]

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)